# Swift iOS tab bar controller badges stop working when segue though a view prior to the tab bar being implemented

Tags: ios, swift

I have quite a complex storyboard. The first section is navigation controller based, this is for actions like sign up, reset password, setting up an account etc.

When the user is past the set up the storyboard introduces and tab bar controller which is used for the general usage of the app. I use badges to tell a user when they have a new message.

All of this works well but I have workflows where the user can change an account setting and this segues to one of the views prior to the tab bar being introduced. After they saved the setting it segues back to the tab bar section.

When the user returns back to the tab bar section of the app the badges stop working. I assume this due to the tab bar not being implemented on a view so the connection to it is lost.

I have made a pseudo storyboard image to help explain the problem. The first time the user comes though this flow the badge works (the little red circle in the image). If they stay within the tab bar section the badges continue to work. When they go from the view with the red circle to the view at the start and then back through the tab bar the badge stops working.

Is there a way to reset this so as the user segues back to the tab bar section it is just like the first time they came in?

[image: pseudo storyboard]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by setting my tab bar as a variable the first time it is used / appears and then setting the badges on the variable rather than the controller. This way as it comes through the flow a second time still works.

```
var rememberTabBar: UITabBarController?
```

then

```
rememberTabBar = tabBarController
```

and

```
rememberTabBar?.tabBar.items![1].badgeValue = "!";
```